How to simulate circuit to demonstrate the benefit of galvanic isolation?
Regarding TI's related video here at first minutes they try to explain why galvanic isolation would save a device but they actually do not explain anything. No grounds mentioned no currents shown no interference is told. I didn't get any insight.
I'm looking for help where two SPICE simulations gives an example of the benefit of such isolation. Two simplistic schematics or circuits where one mimics isolation and the other not so we can see how ne of the device is protected from high current or voltage ect. where one can see CM voltages, grounds ect. to see the point of employing isolation.

What two simulations do you refer to and, if there is any relevance to some images in the video you should embed snap shots. If there is no relevance to the video, why did you link it. Remember that if the link dies, your question must still contain sufficient information to be self contained.

You don't need a SPICE simulation to see the advantage from a safety point-of-view.
If your circuit is connected to the mains and to your membrane keypad, and the membrane wears through your finger can directly contact mains voltage and you could die if there is a path to ground and the mains side happens to be the 'hot/live' one.
As to something you can simulate - imagine a thermocouple amplifier (say 0-40mV full-scale DC amplifier with, say, 40uV resolution) attached to a sensor attached to 240VAC RMS - maybe the end of an open heater element. Say your circuit is grounded so the common-mode voltage is 340V peak.
See how much common-mode rejection at mains frequency you need to be able to get less than 40uV error vs. using galvanic isolation.
For a more advanced topic, figure out where the currents from capacitive coupling across the galvanic isolation flow, and how much error (if any) they cause.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Now imagine the voltage is amplified and digitized and sent across the isolation barrier. The amplifier only sees the 0-40mV since its supply voltages, ground reference and so on are bouncing up and down relative to your ground by +/-340V, at the mains frequency.
Now imagine there is stray capacitance of 1pF coupling from one of the amplifier inputs to the external ground reference. That will have some effect on the measurement. If you are shielding the amplifier think about where the shield should be connected.
Look up 'case within a case'.
This is an analog example, but all signals are analog, and high common mode voltages can easily be bad enough to affect digital signals.

Those Edin Fific edits look counterproductive to me. I mean they are ok but don't read as fluently as the original speff version. There is a personal style thing going on that has been neutralised by the edit. Just saying and not trying to be a sycophant.

@Andyaka, as usual, has described this issue cogently. I would hate for style edits of anyone here to become a regular thing- there are already significant constraints on expression, and the somewhat affected mid-Atlantic conversational style I strive for is important to me, and no doubt the same applies to many others.
